# pgfplotstable an caption below data

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'd like to have a pgfplotstable with the caption below the data, just like with a regular table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
   A & 3 &  4 & 6 \\
   B & 4 &  5 & 7 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Blah}
\end{table}
```

But how to?

I'm trying it like this:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep=comma,
string type,
every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
every last row/.style={after row=\hline },
every last row/.append style={after row={\caption{The caption},
]{data.csv}
```

But i fail with a runaway argument.

Comment: It's rather common to place the caption _above_ a table (also with regular tables!). IMHO you should rethink this layout.

Comment: Just replace the `tabular` environment with the `\pgfplotstabletypeset` one in your first code.

Comment: @cgnieder, I have rules to stick to for this document